# Extract Text from URL in Excel

Tags: excel

I'd like to do the following in Excel:

```
http://www.examplesite.com/ABCD123.php --> /ABCD123.php
http://www.examplesite.com/folder/EFG567.php --> /folder/EFG567.php
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is more generic and is based on assuming that `.com/` will always be in a web address (though clearly that assumption is not robust when one considers .co.uk etc.)

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-(FIND(".com/",A1,1) + 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually figured it out:

```
=RIGHT(H8,LEN(H8)-26)
```

where 26 is the first 26 characters (http://www.examplesite.com).

There must be a more elegant/general solution for this though (i.e. Finding the number of characters before the ".com/")

Answer (score 0):

This is quite hacky as it assumes that the address will always start with http://

=`MID(A1,FIND("/",A1,8),LEN(A1)+1-FIND("/",A1,8))`

Translated:

- character position 8 is the first position after the http:// part
- starting from pos 8, find the position of the first occurence of "/"
- now subtract that position from the overall length of the string and add 1 to avoid losing the final character
- now extract the substring from the position of that first "/" extending for the number of characters that we just calculated